# Git move commits to a branch

Tags: git, branch

Here's the commit graph I have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F (master)
```

And here's what I want:

```
A--B--E--F (master)
    \
     C--D (branch1)
```

from `master` I can create `branch1`, then rebase interactively from `B` both `master`and `branch1`, picking the commits I want, but I think it not straghtforward. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, rebasing is the most straigtforward way to do this. The only other way is a more manual way with git cherry-pick and git reset.

```
git branch branch1 master
git rebase --onto B D master
```

Hope this helps